# Schema error when running update-database command to create identity tables for npgsql data provider

Tags: npgsql

I am manually creating the identity tables for a new ASP.NET 6 project following [this tutorial](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/asp-net-core/asp-net-core-identity-tutorial/). Such tutorial is for MS SQL Server and I am using PostgreSQL so I made the appropriate modifications. Although the process is straightforward, I have a problem when reaching the **update-database** step where I get the following error: **"Couldn´t set schema (Parameter ´schema')"**. My connection string is as follows: **"host=localhost; database=testdb001; schema=testdb001; port=5433; user id=some-user; password=some-password;"**. I found that such error disappears and the identity tables are successfully created if I remove the **schema** parameter in the connection string but tables are created in the **public** schema that PostgreSQL automatically includes when a new DB is created. However, I do not want this to happen because I want to use another schema name. I visited connection strings website for PostgreSQL (https://www.connectionstrings.com/postgresql/) and I see a link for **Npgsql**, and all the examples here **do not** contain the schema parameter. This is the first time that I use npgsql. Is there a way to create the identity tables in a specific schema name?

Maybe a workaround is to specify a schema name in the **search_path** parameter in **postgresql.conf** file but this would lead to add a name every time I define a new schema. I think that the schema name in the connection string is a great choice but I wonder why this is not accepted for npgsql.

Respectfully,

Jorge Maldonado

Comment: Is Search Path a connection string parameter for Npgsql that is equivalent to the common Schema parameter?

Comment: Yes, I just tested. Search Path is a connection string parameter for npgsql that is equivalent to schema parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

For **npgsql** you must use **search path** as a connection string parameter instead of **schema**. So a connection string is as follows

"host=localhost; database=testdb001; **search path**=testdb001; port=5433; user id=some-user; password=some-password;"

and not

"host=localhost; database=testdb001; **schema**=testdb001; port=5433; user id=some-user; password=some-password;"

Regards,
Jorge Maldonado